# content scripts don't attach to intercepted frame on firefox nightly with e10s

Tags: javascript, iframe, firefox-addon-sdk, data-uri, nightly-build

I'm writing a FF addon where when a particular url is loaded in an iframe I intercept the request and load my own content instead by redirecting to a data URI and attaching a content script to the intercepted iframe.  This works brilliantly on every version of FF except nightly with e10s enabled (it works with e10s disabled). In FF nightly with e10s, the frame is intercepted but the content script doesn't attach (it does attach to non-intercepted data uri iframes).

Any ideas on why this isn't working with e10s?

Here's my interception code:

```
function requestListener(event){
    event.subject.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIHttpChannel);
    let url = event.subject.URI.spec;
    if(url == particularURL) {
        event.subject.redirectTo(Services.io.newURI("data:text/html,CONTENT",null, null));
    }
}
```

And here's where I attach my content script using `page mod`'s from FF's addon sdk:

```
pageMod.PageMod({
    include: ["data:*"],
    contentScriptFile: [data.url("myScript.js")],
    contentScriptWhen: "ready",
    attachTo: ["frame"],
    onAttach: function(worker){
        console.log("Attached"); //doesn't run with e10s
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you try with [today's nightly build](http://nightly.mozilla.org/)? We just landed some content script related fixes for e10s.

Comment: @canuckistani will test and let you know

Comment: @canuckistani tried today's build (just downloaded a few minutes ago), unfortunately the issue persists. Independently, the redirect works and the content script injection works, but together they don't

Comment: Sounds like it would be a good idea to [file a bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/) and CC the SDK folks on it (or just @canuckistani who I'd imagine will help you CC the right people)

Comment: It would be really great if you could [file a bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Add-on%20SDK)

Comment: Cool, I've filed a bug and cc'd @canuckistani on it